# Magento 2 How to change event of postcode in customer checkout address form?

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento2.2, shipping, shipping-address

I am developing custom shipping module for magento 2.2.

When you're filling out the Shipping Address form in Magento 2, periodically Magento will make an ajax request for the URL

```
http://magento.example.com/rest/default/V1/guest-carts/[hash]/estimate-shipping-methods
```

I changed postcode text field to autocomplete text field. Now when i type something in text field it make ajax request to above mention url. But after two or three character type, it shows auto suggest fields(which i added in autocomplte) and if I select one from that it doesn't generate any ajax call.

I added autocomplete code in my custom js as per below

```
setTimeout(function(){
        jQuery("input[name='postcode']").autoSuggest(data.items, 
        {
            selectedItemProp: "name", 
            searchObjProps: "name", 
            selectionLimit: 1, 
            minChars: 3,
            selectionAdded: function(elem)
            { 
                result = elem.text();
                getresultval(result);
            }
        }
        );
    }, 6000);
```

So, my problem is when I write on text box it works but when I select something from auto suggestion it doesn't work. That means issue is with binding event of postcode text field.

So how to resolve this?

Comment: Can you upload your code of autocomplete here ?

Comment: @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd. I updated my question with code please check

Comment: When you select from auto suggestion then ajax request should not be call & it's proper way.

Comment: @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd. can you please explain why it's proper way? Because i need to implement this